# Getting regular ConfigurationErrorsException

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2013, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

I am using Stackexchange redis for my MVC app and I am getting regular w3wp exception like below. It doesn't happen on production so I wonder if it is something to do with Visual studio?

Using:
Visual Studio Premium 2013 
Version: 12.0.31101.00 Update 4

I am using the [ASP.NET session state provider](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/05/12/announcing-asp-net-session-state-provider-for-redis-preview-release.aspx) provided by Microsoft and in my web.config it is like so: (I am pointing to an azure redis)

```
<system.web>
  <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore">
      <providers>
        <add name="MySessionStateStore" 
             type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" 
             host="***" 
             accessKey="***" 
             ssl="true"  /> 

      </providers>
  </sessionState>
</system.web>
```

I get this exception every few minutes when I have the app open.

```
Application: w3wp.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was     terminated due to an unhandled exception. 
Exception Info: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException 

Stack: at System.Diagnostics.TraceUtils.GetRuntimeObject(System.String, System.Type, System.String) 
at System.Diagnostics.TypedElement.BaseGetRuntimeObject() 
at System.Diagnostics.ListenerElement.GetRuntimeObject() 
at System.Diagnostics.ListenerElementsCollection.GetRuntimeObject() 
at System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.get_Listeners() 
at System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.WriteLine(System.Object) 
at StackExchange.Redis.SocketManager.Read() 
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) 
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) 
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,  System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object) 
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart(System.Object)
```

Comment: check that you can access your Azure redis cache server from your dev machine (write a console app that uses redis and configure it with your Azure Redis Cache Cluster settings.

Comment: I can access the redis cache server from my dev machine and can get and set values aswell. I just get this error every few minutes.

Comment: I am receiving same error on my development machine any update will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

From exception it looks like it is not coming from session state provider. Problem is due to something else. If exception is due to RedisSessionStateProvider then you would see something like "at Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider*****" in exception.

You can verify this by using different session state. Like try to use "InProc" session state provider and if it still reproduce then it means there is problem with something else and not RedisSessionStateProvider.

If you can provide sample test application that can reproduce this issue and send us on AzureCache@microsoft.com then I can debug it further.